# Android Fragment Error

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a very basic application in which I am trying to create ListFragment on the MainActivity.

I keep on getting the following runtime error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.proto1.listfragment/com.proto1.listfragment.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment

I have two classes.

The first is MainActivity.java as shown below:

package com.proto1.listfragment;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

The second is the class relating to the listfragment SectionsList as shown below:

```
package com.proto1.listfragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

    public class SectionsList extends ListFragment {

        //Create an array to hold the sections
        String sections [] = new String []{
            "Starters", "Mains", "Sides", "Desserts", "Drinks"
        };

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {  

            //Create array adapter to store list of menu sections
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(inflater.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,sections);

            //Set list adapter of fragment
            setListAdapter(adapter);

            return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);     
        }

    }
```

I then have one XML layout file called activity_main as shown below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:orientation = "horizontal"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<fragment 
    android:name = "com.proto1.listfragment.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/sectionFrag"
    android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_height = "fill_parent"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />
```

I am unable to see why this error is being generated. Can someone please shed some light on the issue? Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A FragmentActivity is not a Fragment in itself. But rather, it is a way to easily interact with Fragments. The Fragment you call in your xml should be SectionList.

Comment: I think I see what you mean! I'll try that now.

Comment: Also I have yet to look into it but while on the topic If I was going to dynamically add a new fragment displaying dishes falling under the section clicked would that be done by including a fragmentManager into the code?

Comment: Activity on 3.0+ has a getFragMentManager() method. I think though, that what you want is the getSupportFragmentManager() since you're using the compatibility library.

Answer (score 2):

Edit following into your activity_main xml file

```
<fragment 
android:name = "com.proto1.listfragment.SectionList"
android:id="@+id/sectionFrag"
android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
android:layout_height = "fill_parent"/>
```